# Why Custom SecurityPermission is not loaded?

Tags: c#, .net, security, reflection

I created a CodeAccessSecurityAttribute implementation, witch use stack information to find the target class name, but in some classes the PrincipalPermition is not created, the system uses the previews one instead. What did I miss?

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)] 
public sealed class MyPrincipalPermissionAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    public MyPrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction action) : base(action) { }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        if (Unrestricted)
            return new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace();

        var fullnameArray = new List<String>();
        foreach (var frame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        {
            try
            {
                var method = frame.GetMethod();
                if (method != null && method.ReflectedType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (BaseClass)))
                    fullnameArray.Add(method.ReflectedType.FullName);
            } catch {}
        }

        if (fullnameArray.Count() > 0)
            return new PrincipalPermission(null, fullnameArray[0], true);

        return new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
    }
}
```

And the usage

```
public class MyClassCalledFirstWork: BaseClass
{
    [MyPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class MyClassCalledSecondDontWork: BaseClass
{
    [MyPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry i can't help, but this is some pretty interesting code. What in the world are you trying to accomplish? Why create a list of class names (for method calls on the stack) and then return just the first element in the list (why not break out of loop as soon as you have first one)... and why are you creating PrincipalPermission instances and passing a class name instead of a Role? I dont' get the intent. Good luck :)

Comment: Actually it is simple (at least it shoud be). Each action in the system is executed by a specific class (one for updates, other for exclusions, other for processes, each one for each part of the bussines logic). Since it well organized and divided in classes/namespace, and since the crazy business rule implies each action needs to be authorized (frontend functions to select full namespaces, etc. to simplify), I had two option, trust the capability of the other programmers to spell each role right (one for class, remember) or create a autoatized way.

Comment: And the first element in the list during the execution is a method from a class from the .Net framework security control. Actually my action class is in any place of the stack... and this helped debugging, actually helped me find the problem, but not the solution.

Comment: The Security Attribute only applies to Methods, and the "role" in my case is the class (one main method each class most cases, but same role). That's why I'm using the method class.

Comment: Wouldn't this be "breakable" by inheriting from the decorated class, overriding the method without applying the attribute and also not invoking the base method? I'm also pretty sure that using security attributes in such abundance is a real performance killer.

Comment: In this case, there are only direct inheritance, I mean, all classes are inherited directly form the base class, witch has no security attribute. Even in the case of needed inheritance from a child class, a new security attribute should be placed, according to business rules. And we tested performance, it is still acceptable. Meanwhile, since we can't solve the code above problem, we are using PrincipalPermissionAttribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityattribute.createpermission.aspx) for SecurityAttribute.CreatePermission ():

> "CreatePermission method creates a
> permission object that can then be
> serialized into binary form and
> persistently stored along with the
> SecurityAction in an assembly's
> metadata."
>
> "At compile time,
> attributes convert security
> declarations to a serialized form in
> metadata. Declarative security data in
> metadata is created from the
> permission that this method returns
> that corresponds to this attribute."

It looks like there can be only one permission object (of some type) corresponding with custom CodeAccessSecurityAttribute stored for a specific SecurityAction.
When you check the IL for DoSomething methods you can see that they contain identical permission demands with role defined during the first CreatePermission call.

```
.method public hidebysig virtual instance void 
        DoSomething() cil managed
{
    .permissionset demand
             = {class 'CustomSecurityPermission.Program+MyPrincipalPermissionAttribute, CustomSecurityPermission, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' = {}}
    ...
} // end of method MyClassCalledSecondDontWork::DoSomething

.method public hidebysig virtual instance void 
        DoSomething() cil managed
{
    .permissionset demand
             = {class 'CustomSecurityPermission.Program+MyPrincipalPermissionAttribute, CustomSecurityPermission, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' = {}}
    ...
} // end of method MyClassCalledFirstWork::DoSomething
```

An answer for your second question from comments is:
Instead of using declarative CAS I would use imperative:

```
public sealed class Security
{
    public static IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace();

        var fullnameArray = new List<String>();
        foreach (var frame in stackTrace.GetFrames())
        {
            try
            {
                var method = frame.GetMethod();
                if (method != null && method.ReflectedType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)))
                    fullnameArray.Add(method.ReflectedType.FullName);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        if (fullnameArray.Count() > 0)
        {
            return new PrincipalPermission(null, fullnameArray[0]);
        }
        return new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
    }
}

public class MyClassCalledFirstWork : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Security.CreatePermission().Demand();
        return;
    }
}

public class MyClassCalledSecondDontWork : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Security.CreatePermission().Demand();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that the first call validates the permission, then the second call does not because it has already been validated once?

Comment: Not exactly, permission is evaluated each time, but this is the same permission. Once CreatePermission returns a permission object, for each of those to method calls the same permission object is evaluated.

Comment: Actually I though something like this was happening, I just don't have the base knowledge to investigate. Thanks! Now I have a new problem, how not to pass through this... since I tested and a random code for Role would solve the problem (each permission would be unique, and my code would work), but it is an ugly solution.